# jqMath does not render a formula when content is generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jqmath

I'm looking at HTML which is generated dynamically with JavaScript. Here is how it is done

```
var el = $('body').find('div#my-div.main');
el.html('');
el.append($("<p>If $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a≠0$, then:$$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$</p>"));
```

However no formula is rendered on the page. I see the exact text that is in the p tag. I did check the path to jqMath script and  jqMath css and they are both correct.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call parseMath function once you append the formula like this -

```
        var el = $('body').find('div#my-div.main');
        el.html('');
        el.append("<p>If $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a≠0$, then:$$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$</p>");
        jqMath.parseMath(document.body);
```